# Why nslookup or dig doesn't return nameservers for certain domains?

Tags: whois

Why nslookup or dig doesn't return nameservers for certain domains?

Example:

```
dig @8.8.8.8 NS zzy.pl

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u10-Raspbian <<>> @8.8.8.8 NS zzy.pl
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9801
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;zzy.pl.                                IN      NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
pl.                     1724    IN      SOA     ns1.dropped.net.pl. kontakt.dropped.pl. 2008121404 3600 1800 1209600 3600

;; Query time: 101 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Thu Nov 30 19:15:36 UTC 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 103
```

.

```
nslookup -type=ANY -timeout=10 zzy.pl 8.8.8.8

Server:         8.8.8.8
Address:        8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   zzy.pl
Address: 212.91.7.33
Name:   zzy.pl
Address: 212.91.6.58

Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

From whois:

```
DOMAIN NAME:    
zzy.pl

registrant type:    
organization

nameservers:    
ns1.aftermarket.pl.    
ns2.aftermarket.pl.

(...)
```

Comment: Because the domain owner has not configured DNS.

Comment: How he didn't configure it when whois shows nameservers and nslookup returns A record?

Comment: I should say that he didn't configure DNS _correctly_. I have no idea where the A records are coming from. The zone doesn't appear to have proper NS or even SOA records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;WR**, the main takeaway from this is that when someone sets things up incorrectly, you get strange results.

The `zzy.pl` domain is delegated to

```
ns1.aftermarket.pl.
ns2.aftermarket.pl.
```

These nameservers are misconfigured, rather than having a zone for `zzy.pl` (expected) they have a zone for `pl` (incorrect).

So when you ask these nameservers about `zzy.pl IN NS`, they have no `NS` records (as a direct result o the above mentioned misconfiguration) and answer with a `NODATA` response (meaning that the requested name exists, but has no records of the requested type) with the `SOA` record from their version of a `pl` zone.
Any zone should have at least `SOA` and `NS` at the apex, so `zzy.pl` is broken in this regard.

For reference:

Delegation (normal) from the `pl` TLD nameservers:

```
$ dig @a-dns.pl zzy.pl NS +norec

; <<>> DiG 9.11.1-P3-RedHat-9.11.1-3.P3.fc26 <<>> @a-dns.pl zzy.pl NS +norec
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 51524
;; flags: qr; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;zzy.pl.                                IN      NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
zzy.pl.                 86400   IN      NS      ns2.aftermarket.pl.
zzy.pl.                 86400   IN      NS      ns1.aftermarket.pl.

;; Query time: 25 msec
;; SERVER: 2001:a10:121:1::156#53(2001:a10:121:1::156)
;; WHEN: Thu Nov 30 20:29:50 UTC 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 83
$
```

Authoritative response (expected to match the above, but is instead `NODATA`  and looks as if response is from `pl` zone, which we just moved on from in the previous step):

```
$ dig @ns1.aftermarket.pl. zzy.pl NS +norec

; <<>> DiG 9.11.1-P3-RedHat-9.11.1-3.P3.fc26 <<>> @ns1.aftermarket.pl. zzy.pl NS +norec
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 20464
;; flags: qr aa ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;zzy.pl.                                IN      NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
pl.                     3600    IN      SOA     ns1.dropped.net.pl. kontakt.dropped.pl. 2008121404 3600 1800 1209600 3600

;; Query time: 23 msec
;; SERVER: 212.91.6.36#53(212.91.6.36)
;; WHEN: Thu Nov 30 20:24:23 UTC 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 103

$
```

Querying them for `pl` confirms this:

```
$ dig @ns1.aftermarket.pl. pl NS +norec

; <<>> DiG 9.11.1-P3-RedHat-9.11.1-3.P3.fc26 <<>> @ns1.aftermarket.pl. pl NS +norec
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 63021
;; flags: qr aa ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 3

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;pl.                            IN      NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
pl.                     3600    IN      NS      ns2.dropped.net.pl.
pl.                     3600    IN      NS      ns1.dropped.net.pl.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.dropped.net.pl.     86400   IN      A       212.91.6.36
ns2.dropped.net.pl.     86400   IN      A       212.91.7.38

;; Query time: 23 msec
;; SERVER: 212.91.6.36#53(212.91.6.36)
;; WHEN: Thu Nov 30 20:24:29 UTC 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 111

$
```

Comment: thanx, that explained a lot :-)